# How to gets protected internal methods with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, aop, methodinfo

```
public abstract class BaseAspectAttribute : Attribute
{    
    protected internal virtual void OnMethodBeforeExecuting(object args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Attribute OnMethodBeforeExecuting Work");
    }
}

public class LogAttribute : BaseAspectAttribute
{
    protected override void OnMethodBeforeExecuting(object args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Log Attribute OnMethodBeforeExecuting Work");
    }
}
```

I try get methods in LogAttribute =>

```
object[] customAttributesOnMethod  = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (BaseAspectAttribute), true);
foreach (object attribute in customAttributesOnMethod)
{
    MethodInfo[] methodsInSelectedAttribute = attribute.GetType().GetMethods();
}
```

How to gets protected override methods in LogAttribute?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Call the overload of `GetMethods` which accepts `BindingFlags`. Try something like this:

```
attribute.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx

Comment: Thanks :)  I tried other bindingFlags technics but I didn't use BindingFlags.Instance :/